# Topology - Sierpinski way...

Tags: general-topology

Reading Sierpinski approach to General Topology, I find an interesting comment related to closed sets (determined by the derived sets, and previous in exposition to the opens sets). My question goes this way: Can a topology be defined only by its closed sets? Of course that you can use the De Morgan's laws, but still the open sets working behind courtains... Sierpinski saids not...

Answer (score 2):

A topology $T$ on a set $S$ is, according to the most common definition, a collection of some or all of the subsets of $X$ such that

(i). $\phi \in T$ and $X\in T.$

(ii). If $S\subset T$ then $\cup S\in T.$

(iii). If $S$ is finite and $S\subset T$ then $\cap S\in T.$

The members of $T$ are called the open sets. The complements (in $X$) of members of $T$ are called the closed sets. So we can define $T$ by defining $\{X\setminus t:t\in T\}:$ Let $C$ be a collection of some or all of the subsets of $X$ such that

(i'). $X\in C$ and $\phi\in C.$

(ii'). If $S'\subset C$ then $\cap S'\in C.$

(iii'). If $S'$ is finite and $S'\subset C$ then $\cup S'\in C.$

Then $\{X\setminus c: c\in C\}$ is a topology on $X.$

For a topology $T$ on $X,$ consider the closure operation $Cl_T$ as a function that maps each subset of $X$ to its closure. Then $Cl_T(S')=S'$ iff $S'$ is closed, so  $T=\{X\setminus S': Cl_T(S')=S'\}.$  In particular, in a metric space, the closure of a subset $S'$ is completely and uniquely determined by  the set of convergent sequences of members of $S',$ so two metrics generate the same topology iff they have the  same set of convergent sequences.

And, dually to $Cl_T,$ we can define a topology $T$ by the interior operation $Int_T(S),$ and we have $T=\{S: Int_T(S)=S\}. $